# Force excel 2007 to open in automatic calculation mode by default

Tags: excel, excel-2007, default

I am working with excel application(AddIn) in excel/c#, getting a circular reference error which disappears when I enable automatic recalculation through excel options.
But I want to set Automatic option as default when the file opens, but for some reason it wont let me just save the `.xlsx` file as automatic option enabled. I found some articles stating that you have to have a `personal.xlsx` file in your `XLStart` folder with the desired settings which is used by other sheets as reference, which I created and all my local excel sheets works fine with automatic option by default except this one template (`template.xlsx`). The template is used to populate data and it has 29 sheets in it. So I don't know if that's creating the problem. 
So now when I open excel, it opens the `personal.xlsx` first which has Automatic option enabled, but then, when the `template.xlsx` opens the option changes to "manual". Then I have to manually change it to Automatic option every single time. But all other `.xlsx` files in my PC opens in Automatic option by default.

How to fix this?

Comment: You are going to need to show the code in the file that is causing the unexpected behavior.

Comment: well its not about the code, i just want to change the excel settings to open in automatic calculation mode by default. it is currently working for all other sheets except the workbook  i am working on. The workbook is just a template with multiple sheets in it.

Comment: Nite Angel, Setting "Automatic Calculations" as a default or even adding it to a macro that executes when the sheet is openened is the easy bit. As Issun wrote, you first need to find out where the circular reference is coming from and correct that. Once you corrected the circular reference, we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

As I found in MSDN :

> The user can select the mode through the Excel menu system, or programmatically using VBA, COM, or the C API.

1) You can change the option for a specific range by this:

**Just with VBA:**

```
Range.Calculate (introduced in Excel 2000, changed in Excel 2007)

and 

Range.CalculateRowMajorOrder (introduced in Excel 2007)
```

2) Change option for `Active Worksheet`

> **By Keystroke:** : <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
--VBA:--
ActiveSheet.Calculate

--C API:--
xlcCalculateDocument
```

3) Change option for `All Open Workbooks`

> **By Keystroke:**  <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
--VBA:-- 
Application.Calculate

--C API:-- 
xlcCalculateNow
```

For More read [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx)