# EPPlus: the xlsx file I generate contains cells that do not appear until I edit them in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I have a report that I generate using Epplus (.NET 3.5).

When I open the file with Excel (windows 10) the cells are empty. But When I edit one of those cells I can see the correct formula and if I just press enter (no changes at all) the correct value appears correctly calculated.

Comment: What happens if you use `excelPackage.Workbook.Calculate();` before saving the file? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/8227/creating-formulas-and-calculate-ranges/26436/complete-example-with-formulas#t=201705090817255055113

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus is not a full Excel engine, and does not implement formula calculations.  Think of it as just a way to read/write the file format. Any formula based values will not update until you open it in Excel and perform a recalculation on the sheet or interact with a cell that triggers the calculation.

Comment: I understand. But, isn't there a way to force this? Because, I can't send a report to customers and ask them to "interact" with excel.

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson You could try creating a template with VBA such as here but users will have to allow it to run.  If this is a report then I'd probably do away with the formulas and insert actual values, or add instructions to the first page of the report indicating user should hit F9 to refresh values.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085598/force-excel-2007-to-open-in-automatic-calculation-mode-by-default